# How do I get a list from a specific key of a nested map?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have this var:

```
variable "my_var" {
  type = map(object({
    param      = list(string)
  }))

  default = {
    aaa = {
      param = [
        "sldkjflksdf",
      ]
    }
    bbb = {
      param = [
        "oejkfoekfoe",
        "wewewwe",
        "sssssss"
      ]
    }
    ccc = {
      param = [
        "qqqqqqqqqqqqq",
        "llllllllllll",
        "huhuhuh"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use for_each in a resource to loop over all "param"s in this map. So I want to concat all the param arrays of the nested map and then loop over it with foreach. I tried to use flatten but not sure how it works. Do I need to create a new variable in locals or something?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to show the things you've tried and also any errors that they resulted in or the difference between the expected outputs?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to put this in a local variable like this

```
locals {
  all_params = flatten([for v in values(var.my_var) : v["param"]])
}
```

Then you can write

```
resource "your_resource" "example" {
  for_each = local.all_params
  
  # ... access elements with ${each.value} ...
}
```

Comment: Putting this into a local variable is not necessary, but it is probably more readable. Alternatively, you can also just put ```for_each = flatten([for v in values(var.my_var) : v["param"]])``` directly.